# How to use the Closure Compiler File Watcher in PHP Storm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, google-closure-compiler, file-watcher

I am trying to get Google's closure compiler to work with PHP Storm for minifying javascript files.

I'm not quite sure what i'm doing wrong trying to get this to work and I can't find any guides/tutorials on the web anywhere other than PHP Storm's own docs, which aren't specific enough.

I installed closure compiler using "npm install -g closurecompiler"

It placed it here: "/usr/local/bin/ccjs" (alias of "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/closurecompiler/bin/ccjs")

I then created my file watcher in php storm like so:

[image]

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpsv0.png)

Now when I save a JS file I get the following error:

> /usr/local/bin/ccjs --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js common.js
>
> Illegal source file after options: SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
>
> Process finished with exit code 3

With or without the SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS option it gives an error.

Presumably it simply can't locate the file i'm working with, possibly because of the path it's working from. But then my question is very, very simple, how do I specify the correct path?

I have also tried specifying the exact path (and verified that it is correct) but I just get the same error.

> -compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js $ProjectFileDir$/public/themes/v2/js/$FileName$

For comparison this works for my less file watcher without problem, so I thought $FileName$ would work without issue.

> --no-color --clean-css $FileName$

Answer (score 0):

Correct NPM module is https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler (`npm i google-closure-compiler -g`).

But you can just run the compiler.jar installed with closurecompiler directly (usually `node_modules/closurecompiler/compiler/compiler.jar`) by specifying full path to jar as a Program.

```
Program: path/to/jar/compiler.jar
Arguments: --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js $FileName$
```

Comment: Cheers the node_moduels path to compiler.jar but get an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". I will try again using the NPM module you've linked to.

Comment: In response to my own comment, it seems to be an issue with the Java version on my Mac, related to this question/answer. I will update once i've found a further solution:

http://superuser.com/questions/740064/how-to-install-java-1-7-runtime-on-macos-10-9-mavericks

Comment: yes, it's a java version issue - seems that the compiler.jar was compiled for java 1.7, and you are using some earlier java version (1.6?)